# Issues with HTML and CSS header bar layout

Tags: html, css

I am trying to setup an HTML document that has a fixed position header bar that will contain all of the menu options for the app; The bar should be fixed to the top of the page. The actual content portion of the bar should have a minimum width of *1000px* and should be contained within a wrapper that will fill all remaining space if the page with is >1000px, leaving the content portion centered within.

I have been able to do the following, using a `display: fixed` I can get the bar to stick to the top of the page when scrolling verticaly, but if the page is <1000px, horizontal scrolling does not reveal the rest of the bar, it sticks to its fixed 0,0 position.

Changing to `display: relative`, The bar behaves as expected when scrolling horizontally - I can see the right half of it - however this does not allow it to stay fixed to the top of the document when scrolling vertically. How can I adjust the following such that the bar behaves in this way.

*HTML*:

```
<!-- Page Wrapper -->
<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <div id="nav_wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation Wrapper -->
        <div id="nav_content">

            <!-- Navigation Title -->
            <div id="nav_title">
                some content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Body -->

</div>
```

Navigation Bar *css*:

```
#wrapper {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150%;
    min-width: 1000px;
}

#nav_wrapper {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 48px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    min-width: 1000px;
}

#nav_content {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Again, setting the `nav_wrapper` display style to `fixed` allows me to scroll vertically with the bar sticking to the top but does not allow me to scroll horizontally to view overflow content,

Setting it to `relative` allows me to scroll horizontally to view the overflow content of the bar but does not allow the bar to stick to the top of the page when I scroll vertically, I am looking to be able to do both.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Here is something working on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nkf00r7L/6/)

**Edit**

Maximillian posted an [excellent working example with the behavior I am hoping to achieve](https://jsfiddle.net/2j2mx5mu/), however using javascript.  I am looking for a pure HTML / CSS solution if possible.

Comment: Can you maybe make a fiddle?

Comment: I've never used fiddle before, and when I just tried, it would not render any of the HTML / CSS that I gave it... I can try again and post back with a n update.

Comment: I just edited my post with a jsFiddle link. I have MUCH more css in my actual app - this is just the barebones to get the header to do what I want. It appears as if jsFiddle does not allow a page height of _150%_, so it will not allow to to scroll vertically...

Comment: I had a look and just set the wrapper to an x height so I could see how it scrolls.
I removed the `position: fixed` on the wrapper and added `position fixed` to the` nav_wrapper`. I've updated my answer as I realised you wanted it to scroll horizontally!

Comment: My apologies, my fiddle link was actually a little bit different then my post - the things that you changed I already have. I am looking for the same behavior that comes from Maximillian's fiddle link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you can't get fixed position divs to scroll along with the window by using pure HTML and CSS, so here is a JavaScript solution.

**Live Demo:**

```js
var nav_wrapper = document.getElementById("nav_wrapper");
window.onscroll = function() {
    nav_wrapper.style.left = -pageXOffset + "px";
};
```

```css
#wrapper {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    background: gray;
}

#nav_wrapper {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 48px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    min-width: 1000px;
    background: blue;
}

#nav_content {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<!-- Page Wrapper -->
<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <div id="nav_wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation Wrapper -->
        <div id="nav_content">

            <!-- Navigation Buttons -->
            <div id="nav_main">
                Buttons
            </div>

            <!-- Navigation Title -->
            <div id="nav_title">
                Title
            </div>

            <!-- Navigation Options -->
            <div id="nav_options">
                Options
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Body -->

</div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/2j2mx5mu/

Comment: This is awesome, much appreciated. I will see if anyone else can post an answer using pure HTML / CSS, if nobody can come up with a solution, I will use this :)

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this fixes your issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/nkf00r7L/4/
I changed the following css:

```
#wrapper {
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2000px;
    min-width: 1000px;
    background-color: #DDDDDD;

}

#nav_wrapper {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 48px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    min-width: 1000px;
    background-color: #000000;

}
```

### Updated:

I noticed you wanted it to scroll horzontally!! I've added `overflow: scroll` on the wrapper.

https://jsfiddle.net/nkf00r7L/5/

Comment: Hi James, I appreciate the effort, however I messed up and the posting in my fiddle link was slightly different then what I had in my question. What I originally posted already had these changes. I am looking to get the same behavior as is shown by Maximillian's fiddle link.